# Adding an element to a nested python list

Tags: python, list, nested

I am learning Python and am having trouble with lists. I want to create a list containing a nested list `e.g. a = [1, [2]]`. I then want to 'append' `4` to the nested list making `a[1,[2,4]]` and then insert `3` between `[2,4]` making `a[1,[2, 3, 4]]`.
`a.append(4)` does `[1,[2],4]`, I cannot find a way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> a = [1, [2]]
>>> a[-1].append(4)
>>> a
[1, [2, 4]]
>>> a[-1].insert(1, 3)
>>> a
[1, [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Easy when you know how.

Comment: @Twoxmelles: Look at one of the first chapters in the tutorial: [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).